# Symfony 1.4 dynamically/programmatically set delivery_strategy for swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

So I am working on Symfony 1.4 and I am looking for a way to programmatically set a different delivery_strategy than what I have in my factories.yml.

My code for initialising the mailer and the transport is as below:

```
$transport  = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('MY SMTP SERVER');
$transport->setUsername($api_user);        
$transport->setPassword($api_key);        
$swift      = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);                        
$response   = $swift->send($message);
```

For example in my factories.yml I have the strategy set to spool but here I want to set it to realtime.

Any way of doing this programmatically?

Comment: Could you please edit your post and place a question? We've got no question.

Comment: Which delivery strategy would you like to use instead?

Comment: With the code you have it should not matter because because you are using Swift directly, not using the `sfMailer` extension of it. Moreover you can also create a new instance of `sfMailer` without using factories directly... You just specify an array of options and the event dispatcher.

Comment: @prodigitalson in this case what delivery strategy will it default to then (without sfmailer)? Could you maybe provide an example of the sfMailer option? Also put it up as an answer if you want so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: @P.R.Ribeiro Does it matter? Realtime as I said in the question.

Comment: It does matter. ;-) Realtime means it'll be sent right away. So the code you're already using should do that. The documentation link have more info http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html .

Comment: Swift itself has no concept of "delivery strategy" asfar as Swift is concerend that is determined by the Transport class and/or plugins you use. The delivery strategy is a symfony thing used to describe "configuration modes" for the underlying Swift Mailer instance. For example realtime uses one of the traditional transport classes (smtp, sendmail, mail), while spool uses `SpoolTransport`, and none uses `MailTransport` and a special plugin. [Take a look in the constructor here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/1.4/lib/mailer/sfMailer.class.php)

Comment: @P.R.Ribeiro indeed you were both right! I didn't fully understand this until I read the above and the docs you provided. Please put up an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real-time means it'll be sent right away. So the code you're already using should do that. The documentation link have more info swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html.

Delivery strategy is a Symfony concept. Swiftmailer does not have it. All you send using Swiftmailer directly will be sent right away, corresponding to the Symfony 'realtime' delivery strategy.